# How can I set current typed characters manually on bootstrap maxlength?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/0tx58ma1/6/

```js
(function($){
  $('[maxlength]').maxlength({
    alwaysShow: true,
    separator: ' / ',
    preText: '',
    postText: '',
    showMaxLength: true,
    showCharsTyped: true,
    placement: 'bottom-right-inside',
    showOnReady: true,
  });

  $("#btnReplaceText").click(function(){
    $("#test").val("ypaaaa");
    $("#text").show();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-maxlength/1.10.0/bootstrap-maxlength.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" maxlength="10" placeholder="please click button" value="">
<br>
<button type="button" id="btnReplaceText">click me</button>
<p id="text" style="display: none;">I wanna set current typed characters when I push button. How can I ???</p>
```

This plugin counts the number of characters currently typed in real time.

If you are typing with a keyboard, it will count the number of characters as you expect.

However, if you substitute a string with a click event using jQuery, it will not count the number of characters because it is not typing.

I would like the current character count to appear in the character counters when the button is clicked.

I wanna set current typed characters when I push button. How can I ???

Comment: Could you please be more clear on your problem statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard the solution to this problem from developer.

It seems that we can count the number of characters by doing the following.

```
$("#test").val("ypaaaa") 

to

$("#test").val("ypaaaa").trigger('input')
```